# Collect data each time for loop is completed

Tags: python

The inner for loop looks for word "Port" each time a particular error_str is found. Inside each error_str there are multiple word "Port" . I want to store letters after word "Port" in each error_str . Once a particular error_str is scanned I want store those letters and stop the loop and print them. Below code just appends all of them.

```
for iterate in files:
    latest = path + os.path.basename(iterate)
    with open(latest) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        print(lines)
        error_str = json.dumps(lines)
        for port_found in re.finditer('Port', error_str):
            i = port_found.end() + 1
            port_failed_last = error_str[port_found.end()] + error_str[i]
            # array_port_append_failed.append(port_failed_last)
            print("CHANGE", port_failed_last)
```

Comment: Please [edit] to show the output you expect.

Comment: You can use generator expression and walrus assignment

Answer (score 0):

> store letters after word "Port" in each error_str

To translate this literally, you need a list.

```
found = []
for port_found in re.finditer('Port', error_str):
    i = port_found.end() + 1
    found.append(error_str[i:])
print(found)
```

> Once a particular error_str is scanned I want store those letters and stop the loop

You can compare the string from the found position onward

```
found = []
# for ...:
    i = port_found.end() + 1
    scanned = error_str[i:]
    if scanned == "particular":
        break  # stop the loop
    else:
        found.append(scanned)
print(found)
```

Comment: I have just executed the first half of your recommendation. I see that found.append(error_str[i:]) prints our the entire error_str. error_str is a json file. However,  I want the three letter after word "Port" in error_str.

Comment: Well, your question literally said "letters after word". Your regex knows nothing about the word immediately after "Port". If that is what you want, then you would want capture groups... If you literally want "three letters after" then use `error_str[i:i+3]`, but this will fail if "Port" is found at the very end of the string... Like I said, edit your question to show your inputs and expected outputs